# Running a global method with arguments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble running a method in my program.cs

For example, this is in my program.cs:

```
public string tryConn(string address, string name, string password)
{
      string connString = (address + ':' + name + ';' + password);
      try
      {
            connect(connString);
            return true;
      }
      catch
      {
           return false;
      }
}
```

And on a form, within a buttons _Click method, I'm trying to run this function like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       bool _conn = WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.tryConn('127.0.0.1','root','toor')
}
```

It's simply just not having any of it, can anyone describe the steps I'd take to be able to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make tryConn `static` method to call it with class. You can read more about static class and static methods over [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
public static string tryConn(string address, string name, string password)
{
        string connString = (address + ':' + name + ';' + password);
        try
        {
            connect(connString);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark this method as `static`, otherwise it is an instance method and must be called on an instance of Program.

```
public static string tryConn(string address, string name, string password)
```

But when it is `static`, it *cannot access any non-static fields or methods* of the class, so the `connect` method must be `static`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Add `static` keyword for the method's declaration:

```
public static string tryConn(string address, string name, string password)
{
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

something like

```
public static string tryConn(string address, string name, string password)
```

Also maybe have a look at [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)